# Javascript detect if native emoji is supported

Tags: javascript, emoji

I would like to detect if native emoji is supported.
Only if it does not, I will then load emoji font to save bandwidth and also make the application look more native.

However, as I search through the Internet, I only found someone using `userAgent` to check if emoji is supported or not.
For example, the below code is from https://github.com/github/g-emoji-element/blob/master/emoji-detection.js,

```js
export function isEmojiSupported(): boolean {
  const onWindows7 = /\bWindows NT 6.1\b/.test(navigator.userAgent)
  const onWindows8 = /\bWindows NT 6.2\b/.test(navigator.userAgent)
  const onWindows81 = /\bWindows NT 6.3\b/.test(navigator.userAgent)
  const onFreeBSD = /\bFreeBSD\b/.test(navigator.userAgent)
  const onLinux = /\bLinux\b/.test(navigator.userAgent)

  return !(onWindows7 || onWindows8 || onWindows81 || onLinux || onFreeBSD)
}
```

Though the regular expression may not be perfect, as Firefox in Windows 7 does support Emoji as from http://caniemoji.com/.

However, as different browser or libraries may have different set of emoji, some emoji may render perfectly in one browser, and some just not render very well.

So is there a better method other than using `userAgent` to check if Emoji is supported?

Comment: It’s possible to put emojis on a canvas, using `fillText`, then get the colors of the pixels of the canvas. If the pixels aren’t always grayscale, emojis are supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There used to be a technique to measure the width of an element containing text in 2 different fonts to see if a font is supported by seeing if a fallback font was used.

A similar technique can be used with emojis by taking advantage of emoji sequences that collapse onto a single emoji.

If a browser supports emojis it will render 1 glyph for emojis that are made up of 2 sequences. If it doesn't, it will render 2 glyphs.

```
var trinidad = String.fromCodePoint(0x1F1F9, 0x1F1F9);
var hammerpick = String.fromCodePoint(0x2692);

function getWidth(s) {
  var n = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("span"));
  n.appendChild(document.createTextNode(s));
  var w = n.offsetWidth;
  n.parentNode.removeChild(n);
  return w;
}

console.log(getWidth(trinidad) === getWidth(hammerpick) ? "supported": "not supported");
```

Comment: This is quite an interesting idea, that I have never thought of.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to detect, I would suggest loading the font with all the glyphs you want, and using `font-display: swap` in your CSS.

Then, your page can still be shown while the loading of this extra font is still occurring.

See also:  https://css-tricks.com/font-display-masses/

Comment: Of course, this works, but in this case, if the browser natively supports emoji, then I will override browser emoji to my emoji (says twitter emoji). And it does not sound too good to me.In addition, it means downloading a new font from the Internet, even if the browser has one, is it a good idea?

Comment: @CHANist You will be loading your preferred font over the browser font, yes.  And yes, you will be downloading a new font but it only has to download once.  There isn't a way for you to detect which specific glyphs are supported by a particular font on a particular system, short of some canvas hacks like Sebastian's idea.  You can either have all the overhead of building something that initializes a canvas, draws, then detects support and compares to a font (which you'll have to load some basis of comparison...), or do it the usual way.